# Rails, Installed Gem version and Gemfile.lock version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a problem.

Gemfile.lock is always committed if bundle is updated.

And today, when I deploy web application, I see this error message,

```
Could not find jwt-1.5.3 in any of the sources
```

`jwt-1.5.2` is installed in deployed server at shared gem path.

I think bundle install new `jwt-1.5.3` gem because the specified version (1.5.3) in Gemfile.lock and installed version (1.5.2) is not equal.

Why cannot bundle install jwt gem?

Should bundle install that gem if Could not find jwt-1.5.3?

Comment: `Gemfile.lock is always committed if bundle is updated`? Do you mean if the Gemfile is updated? Or do you mean if `bundle` is run?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delete the `Gemfile.lock` file. Then `bundle install` again. Hopefully it will install again with `jwt-1.5.3`. But make sure you have mentioned the version of jwt in gem file.

Comment: oh.. After I remove Gemfile.lock and bundle install again in my local, I deploy again. and it's work.. Could you guess why ? um...

Comment: Gemfile.lock file actually lock the installed version previously.If you like the answer please give a upvote. Thank you

Comment: It isn't necessary to prompt someone to select an answer within an hour of asking and answering. Often good answers take time to formulate, and the earth takes 24 hours to rotate, so 24 hours is a reasonable time to suggest the OP to select an answer. Even then, if I was to prompt them, I'd do so as a comment to the question, not to the answer.

Comment: I know this is old, but don't do this. Just run `bundle update jwt`. Removing your Gemfile.lock can cause a lot of issues with your app, removing it and then running bundle install will update every gem that doesn't have a version specified in the Gemfile.

Answer (score 3):

Oh.. I know why.

https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt/versions/1.5.3

jwt 1.5.3 is yanked because of some reasons. So 1.5.3 version isn't in repository..!

Comment: Here's the complete discussion about the yank reason https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/issues/132

Comment: This is the best answer; I was looking for this; thanks